# Синие выступы

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от синих выступов за внешнюю сторону рамки?

[image: снимок]

Answer (score 1):

Ну у вас либо width больше, чем нужно, либо padding, третьего не дано :)

Comment: Вот, что получается изображения рамки, имеют по краям прозрачный фон, чтобы была видна тень от нее, но получается, что наверное из за этого цвет бекграунда вылазит по сторонам!?? Как быть?